# ImportError: No module named seqfmt

Tags: python, groovy, cython

I am running a python script from Groovy via:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python /Users/afrieden/Projects/hgvs/hgvs/tests/test_gsg_variants.py");
String s = null;
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(s);
}

// read any errors from the attempted command
System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

However it calls what looks like a cython library seqfmt.  (seqfmt.c and seqfmt.pyx).

I have added it in the sys import:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/afrieden/Projects/hgvs/build/lib/")
sys.path.append("/Users/afrieden/pythonLib/pygr-0.8.2/")
sys.path.append("/Users/afrieden/pythonLib/pygr-0.8.2/pygr/seqfmt.pyx")
sys.path.append("/Users/afrieden/pythonLib/pygr-0.8.2/pygr/seqfmt.c")
import hgvs
import csv
import hgvs.utils
from pygr.seqdb import SequenceFileDB
```

Any thoughts on how I can get it to run?  Thanks!

EDIT:

It does work with python from the command line just fine.

Comment: I assume it works when you call the python script directly from the command line?

Comment: ooops yes sorry it does let me add that in!

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying your script slightly, does this work:

```
def proc = [ 'bash', '-c', 'python /Users/afrieden/Projects/hgvs/hgvs/tests/test_gsg_variants.py' ].execute()

StringWriter out = new StringWriter()
StringWriter err = new StringWriter()

proc.waitForProcessOutput( out, err )

println 'Here is the standard output of the command:'
println out.toString()

println 'Here is the standard error of the command (if any):'
println err.toString()
```

Comment: still fails with same error: `ImportError: No module named seqfmt`